# How use space among function parameters in python

Tags: python-3.x, indentation

```
def superDigit(n , k):
```

## while calling the function we use like this

```
superDigit(2 , 4)
```

## But I want to use space among parameters  like this

```
superDigit(2 4)
```

## How do I write code for using the space among parameters???

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Python's way of separating arguments is with a comma - why would you want to use space instead?

Comment: you could write your own interpreted language with its very own calling convention that works exactly how you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no effort to understand the existing syntax

Comment: I found a question how ever it's input like this for function.

Comment: Can you show that question?? There is no language that I know of that accepts space as separating arguments/parameters

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a very good solution, you can try to do something like this:

```py
def functions(args):
    args.split(' ')
    arg1 = args[0]
    arg2 = args[1]
    # ...
    print(args1, args2)
```

So I guess a makeshift solution? But it may be slightly annoying. I recommend just using standard syntax.
Note that it'll have to be a string though, e.g. `superdigit('2 4')`. I hope you don't mind. To be honest though, just use the standard syntax.